# Can a monitor connected with Thunderbolt 2 power a mid-2013 MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

Want to buy an external monitor for a mid-2013 MacBook Air. Am wondering whether one with a Thunderbolt 2 port will be better in that it will also power the laptop. Else I'll buy one with USB-C to power the next laptop I buy, and use a USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 cable/adapter for now.

Can a monitor connected with Thunderbolt 2 power a mid-2013 MacBook Air?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a thunderbolt cable transmit power?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/124485/can-a-thunderbolt-cable-transmit-power)

Comment: @NimeshNeema The linked question is related but subtly different: it is about host-to-device, whereas this question appears to be about device-to-host power.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, no. While Thunderbolt 1 & 2 can power downstream devices, the maximum amount of power is not that much, and there does not appear to be any provision for powering *upstream* devices including the host computer. **Macs can certainly not be powered/charged via a Thunderbolt 1 or 2 port.** Thunderbolt 2-to-3 adapters do not change this and do not retroactively enable more power delivery on the Thunderbolt 2 side.

The Apple Thunderbolt display actually had a MagSafe connector in addition to its Thunderbolt cable in order to power a connected MacBook.

> Else I'll buy one with USB-C to power the next laptop I buy, and use a USB-C to Thunderbolt 2 cable/adapter for now.

If I understand you correctly, your plan is to buy a display with USB-C as the display signal input and power delivery, and connect it to the Thunderbolt 1 or 2 port on a Macbook?

This won't work. There are reports that you can do this with Thunderbolt 3 based displays (e.g. LG Ultrafine 5K but note your MacBook Air does not support 5K), but it most definitely will *not* work with a display that simply uses USB-C with its DisplayPort alternate mode. It's not clear exactly which adapter you were planning to use but:

1. Simple USB-C to (Mini) DisplayPort cables can only be run in one direction: USB-C on the host (computer) to a DisplayPort on the display.
2. Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapters such as Apple's only work for transmitting Thunderbolt signals, not USB or USB-C's DisplayPort alternate mode.

**If you want to buy a display that will power a future USB-C based laptop, choose a model where the USB-C port/cable with power delivery is merely one of multiple ports. You can then use either an HDMI or DisplayPort input on the display to connect to your current MacBook Air.**

Note that the 2013 MacBook Air only supports DisplayPort 1.1 and HDMI 1.2, which limits the maximum resolution and refresh rate:

- DisplayPort 1.1 supports up to 2560x1600 at 60Hz; depending on the specific Intel GPU and driver you *may* be able to drive a 4K display at **30Hz**. (From personal experience, the early 2013 MacBook **Pro** and the 2012 Mac Mini have trouble with this; during boot and in macOS 10.12 and earlier, there is image corruption. Once booted up, 10.13 and newer seem to work ok at 4K @ 30Hz. The 2013 Air has a slightly newer CPU/GPU, so I'm not sure how it behaves.)
- HDMI 1.2 (via Mini DisplayPort to HDMI cable on a MacBook Air) only supports up to 1920x1200 at 60Hz.